# Setting debug=false in web.config as part of build

Tags: .net, asp.net, build-automation, nant

Is it possible to instruct the aspnet_compiler to set debug=false in the web.config?

My intention is to automate this as part of the nant build process. I am open to suggestions other than xml parsing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you thought about using `<xmlpoke>`?

```
<xmlpoke file="${Build.WebConfig}" 
    xpath="/configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug" 
    value="false">
</xmlpoke>
```

[NAnt Home Page](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

[XML Poke Documentation](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.86-beta1/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html)

Comment: I recommend adding links to the NAnt home page and the xmlpoke documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using entirely different config files for each environment(prod, test, staging in our case). Depending on the build you would just use the required config, no mess, less fuss. [Hanselmen](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx) has example on how to do this in Visual Studio and if you read the first comment Phil Hack has got it working with [NAnt](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2007/09/22/ManagingMultipleEnvironmentConfigurationsThroughNAnt.aspx).

```
 <target name="configMerge">  
     <copy file="${sourcefile}"  
         tofile="${destinationfile}" overwrite="true">  
       <filterchain>  
         <expandproperties />  
       </filterchain>  
     </copy>  
   </target>
```

In Addition, if you are using VS 2010 you can now use [web.config transforms](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/16/visual-studio-2010-web-config-transforms.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The way I tackle this is I have seperate configuration files for each deployment environment:

- Production
- Staging
- Development

Upon the "build script", I copy the config files for the type I am building.  For example, on Staging I would copy the /configs/staging/*.config into the root of the website.  Then, my script would call aspnet_compiler to compile the application.

Comment: +1. I actually take this a step further and deploy multiple web.config files, named web.config.empty, web.config.default, etc... that way 1) I never overwrite an existing web.config file, and 2) users can review the settings used in different ways.

Comment: It also helps when you have a 10+ person team of developers, all with SQL installed locally, Vista IIS7 vs XP's IIS6 configs, etc.  The team just has to be trained that "when a config is changed, make sure is propogated throughout all other config files"

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this tool as part of my build chain.
It allows conditional configuration settings within a single xml file based on build settings.

http://xmlpreprocess.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Using web deployment projects you can swap out different sections of your web.config after your build.