# What's a good way to remove debug="true" from web.config on publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I use VS 2008 to develop and I use CCNet to build, test and deploy our applications to a staging server. I would like to be able to remove the `debug="true"` setting from web.config as part of the deployment process.

I know I could just set `<deployment retail="true"/>` in machine.config, but I don't always have that much access the servers we deploy to. I could just write a bit of code to strip the setting from the web.config, but I was wondering if there was a way I could do it out of the box with msbuild or CCNet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) and do:

```
<XmlUpdate 
        XmlFileName="web.config" 
        XPath="//configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug" 
        Value="false"/>
```

Or you can use various built-in Visual Studio transformation techniques:

- [VS2010+ has a full set of transformation techniques built just for this which does it very cleanly:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx)

> `<configuration xmlns:xdt="...">`
>   `<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug,batch)">`
>   `</compilation>`
>   `</configuration>`

- VS2005 and 2008 Web Deployment projects allow you to substitute portions of a web config ([as Paddy linked to](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx))
- Not certain but MSDeploy has some form of capability around this
- NAnt has an [xmlpoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678455/hidden-features-of-nant)

NB this is a duplicate of 
[Setting debug=false in web.config as part of build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678096/setting-debugfalse-in-web-config-as-part-of-build/678137#678137) (Which I found too late; have put a vote to close on this)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have supplied web deployment projects for download - these are MS build projects that have a bit of a front end in VS - they allow you to swap out config sections.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My solution for **CCNET** with the **Web.config transformation**:

```
<tasks>
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>E:\VersionesCC\Trunk_4\SBatz\Gertakariak_Orokorrak\GertakariakMS\Web</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>GertakariakMSWeb2.vbproj</projectFile>
        <targets>Build</targets>
        <timeout>600</timeout>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
        <buildArgs>
            /noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Release /v:diag
            /p:DeployOnBuild=true
            /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
            /p:DeployTarget=Package
            /p:_PackageTempDir=E:\Aplicaciones\GertakariakMS2\Web
        </buildArgs>
        </msbuild>
</tasks>
```